# SQL Group by with where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a table like this

```
TestID    SectionID    Section    
-------------------------------
   1           5         1
   1           6         2
   2           7         1
   2           8         2
   3           9         1
   4           10        1
   4           11        2
   5           12        2
   6           13        1
   6           14        2
   7           15        2
   8           16        1
   8           17        2
---------------------------------
```

The scenario is to return testID with **sectionID 12 and 15**. So the condition is return those rows where **non repeating testID and the section should be 2**. Thus sectionID 12 and 15 is returning because, for there testIDs (5 and 7 respectively) there is only row for that testid 5 and 7 and there section is 2. Row 3 wont be selected because even its testid not repeating, but its section is **1**

I tried using group by

```
select testid, count(section)
from #temp
where section = 2 
group by testid, section
having count(section) = 1
```

But its returning wrong testids.

Here is the code snippet with the data I've tried.

```
create table #temp (testid int,sectionid int,section int)
insert into #temp (testid,sectionid,section)
values (1,5,1),(1,6,2),(2,7,1),(2,8,2),(3,9,1),(4,10,1),(4,11,2),(5,12,2),(6,13,1),(6,14,2),(7,15,2),(8,16,1),(8,17,2)
select testid,count(testid) from #temp where section=1 
group by testid having count(testid)=1
```

**So the expected result is**

```
TestID
---------
  5
  7
---------
```

Comment: Show us the expected result as well.

Comment: `But its returning wrong testids.` Where are they? And what are the _right_ ones?

Comment: @jarlh modified the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the condition:

```
select testid
from #test t
group by testid
having count(*) = 1 and
       min(section) = 2;
```

The first condition checks that there is only one row.  The second condition checks that the `section` value in the row is "2".  Note that with just one row, you could use either `min()` or `max()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're SELECT statement is almost correct, you only have to remove section from the GROUP BY condition:

```
select testid, count(section) 
from #temp 
where section=2 
group by testid
having count(section)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical functions

```
select testid,sectionid,section from
(
  select testid,count(*) over (partition by testid) c,sectionid,section
  from #temp
  ) a
where c=1
and section=2
```

First we count rows pr testid in a subselect, and the filter it based on the count and section=2

Answer (score 0):

placing of where condition is wrong

```
      select #temp.testid from #temp inner join 
( select testid,count(0) as count from #temp group by testid having count(0)=1 ) A
      ON A.testid = #temp.testid AND #temp.section<>1
```